# Not able to progress past loading CSV in New Dataset dialog

Tags: carto, csv, gui

We're getting some strange behavior in the connect dataset dialog, where, once we've selected a CSV file for upload, we get no button or feedback to continue the process.

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5g8zbgih2spdu9/Screenshot%202016-01-20%2011.13.05.png?dl=0)

Anyone else seeing this weird behavior, or have a fix? We're using Firefox, several versions, on OSX and Win.

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oriolbx was on the right track. Turned out our version of Firefox was no longer supported. Updated and fixed the problem.